# fullScreen js iOS safari

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, zooming, fullscreen

I'm trying to make an image go to full screen when clicked on for mobile using [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/). However when I run the iOS simulator the line `if (screenfull.enabled)` is not passing.

Does anyone know how I can make this work for safari mobile? I'm trying to use it to make a pinch and zoom feature for images on my website.

Answer (score 1):

I learned, iOS Safari does not support the native Fullscreen API http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen (which is what screefull.js uses underneath to implement it's API). You can try

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="YES">
```

But only work with "Add to home screen"